# jQuery scroll animation slows with background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

My page employs a parallax design, where there are several pretty high resolution photos in the background that take up most of the page.  When the page loads, the landing page is a large, high-resolution background image with a small table of contents ('about', 'music', 'contact').  When you click one, it should scroll to the appropriate part of the page, and it does.  Here's the jQuery code for one such element:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$("h3[class='About']").click(function() {
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $("div[class*='About']").offset().top
        }, 2000, 'swing');
    });
```

The scrolling works fine, but it clearly lags and is a bit choppy.  When I remove the images from the site, it performs very smoothly.  I'm wondering what I could do to circumvent this issue.  I have tried compressing the images, but it has done almost nothing to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I think you've found the problem: high resolution images are hard work for the browser to render, and you can't help that. You're doing everything correctly.

There'll be a small benefit for using jQuery >3.0 because it animates with `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`.

Resizing the images to lower resolution helps. Compressing the images by reducing jpeg quality or whatever doesn't because the images are uncompressed before the browser renders them.